# Error configuring IBM WAS 7 server adapter in Eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse-kepler, ibm-was

I'm trying to install Eclipse IBM-WAS 7 tools in eclipse kepler from

ibm websphere - http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/kepler

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/kepler/plugins/com.ibm.jee.was.descriptors.ui_1.3.150.v20140602_0512.jar.
Connection reset

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Go to this URL: [WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse Kepler](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Kepler)

You should see several install icons in the page. You will find one labelled WebSphere® Application Server V7.0.

*Drag and drop this Install icon onto the Eclipse toolbar and then follow the prompts.* It should work. Please let me know if you face any other issues/errors.

If the above URL expires, you can also go to Eclipse Market place and search "IBM WebSphere Application Server V7.x Developer Tools for Kepler" and install the developer tools from there as well.

Comment: Please include relevant into on-site so that it is available when links expire

Comment: Included relevant info